# Accessing properies of an Entity assigned to a var

Tags: c#, .net

Please help me understand this. I have sort of a factory that looks like this

```
public static class  FactoryForAnything
{
    public static object GetInstanceOf<T>() where T : class
    {
         return Activator.CreateInstance(IsType<T>(), true);
    } 
    private static Type IsType<T>()
    {
        if (typeof(T).IsSubclassOf(typeof(EntityBaseSupertype)) == true)
        {
            return typeof(T);
        }
        else if (typeof(T).IsSubclassOf(typeof(ValueObject<>)) == true)
        {
            return typeof(T);
        }
        else
            return null;
    }
```

**Intention** accept a class as parameter and return an object of that class

```
EntityBaseSupertype hon =(EntityBaseSupertype) FactoryForAnything.GetInstanceOf<User>(); 
var hon = FactoryForAnything.GetInstanceOf<User>();
```

**Calling the factory with EntityBaseSupertype** gets me the object and it is referenced by the abstract base class of all entities, so I am able to access filed/properties/members of the object.
**Calling the factory with var** gets me the object ,but it does not give me access to fields/properties and so on.
I understand that this is an ugly design and it will not be used, but my question lies in Why cant I access object using a var?
Why is that ?

Comment: Because... your method returns `object`? Have it return `T` instead (you'll need to do an explicit cast, of course).

Comment: I'm not sure but you could force the constraint to have a empty constructor with `new()` and then use it to instance your `T` generic type.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, `var` is just a keyword to shorten the writing needed for a known `Type`, when declaring a variable.
That means the compiler will determine the explicit type of the variable, **based on the usage**.
So, in your code, the line:

```
var hon = FactoryForAnything.GetInstanceOf<User>();
```

is equivalent to:

```
object hon = FactoryForAnything.GetInstanceOf<User>();
```

since the compiler (as well as `IntelliSense`) bases its member lookup on ***the `Type` of the variable accessed***, which in this case is `object` (or one of its base-classes. Which do not exist because, well... this is `object` and it has no base-class).

When compiling the following code:

```
EntityBaseSupertype hon = (EntityBaseSupertype) FactoryForAnything.GetInstanceOf<User>();
```

You are doing two things:

- [Explicitly casting](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173105.aspx) the `object` returned from `GetInstanceOf` to `EntityBaseSupertype`, which will throw an [`InvalidCastException`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.invalidcastexception.aspx) if the returned `Type` is invalid for that cast.
- Assigning the casted value to a variable of `Type` `EntityBaseSupertype`.

Then, the member lookup can find the members of `EntityBaseSupertype` and it's base classes.

---

***Some side notes:***

- `GetInstanceOf<T>` will always return an `object` of `Type` `T`, therefore you should change it's signature to:

  ```
  public static T GetInstanceOf<T>() where T : class
  ```

  If it might return a `Type` which is not `T` then this method is risky because the code which will invoke it can get unexpected results and should not be doing the casts itself.
- In cases like this you should consider using `IsAssignableFrom` instead of `IsSubclassOf` in order to support [*Covariance* and *Contravariance*](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee207183.aspx).
- Converting the returned value with the [`as`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cscsdfbt.aspx) keyword is safer since it returns `null` when failed, instead of throwing an `InvalidCastException`.
- Naming a non-boolean method `IsXXXXX` makes athe code a little bit less readable, therefore, a little bit less maintainable, also your `IsType` method returns `null`, which can cause your other method to throw an unindicative `Exception` when the `Type` is invalid.

Answer (score 0):

The compiler attempts to determine the real type of a `var` from the code, but for

```
var hon = FactoryForAnything.GetInstanceOf<User>();
```

`object` is the best it can do. The compiler does not have access to object metadata, because it is not actually executing and passing an object instance.

You can get checking of metadata with

```
EntityBaseSupertype hon =  FactoryForAnything.GetInstanceOf<User>() as EntityBaseSupertype;
```

But this is a run-time check. The compiler will interpret `hon` as an `EntityBaseSupertype` and allow you to access public properties and members. The CLR will look at the object metadata at runtime and return null if the object is not assignable to `EntityBaseSupertype`, whereas the cast will throw an InvalidCastException if this is not assignable.